Problems changing the paper size in printer driver settings
I am loosing my mind over a simple problem. I want to print a word document on photo paper as I organise my notes in a Zettelkasten. But somewhere in the chain, the paper size seems to be wrong, the printer tells me that the selected size doesn't match with the detected paper size.
The material photo paper is 10 x 15 cm
The word document is in 10 x 15 cm, but in landscape format. As this is selected when I click print, I figured this is not a problem (?)
The printer is set to 10 x 15 cm photo paper
Now this leaves open the question of printer server paper sizes and the paper size selected in printer properties.
In the printer server tab I created a new format called "Zettel", size 10 x 15cm
(german screenshot)
But "apply" (german: übernehmen) is greyed out. Every time I open these settings, there is another format selected.
Consequently I cannot use this setting for the "available paper" in the printer properties
(sorry for german again)
Nor in the printing setting
(and again)
I have been raging for hours at the fact, that one just cannot simply choose one of the most standard photo paper sizes.... I feel like missing something stupid here. I would be crazy thankfull, if somebody could help!

It would be awkward, but you could probably put your Word text in a 6x4 textbox and rotating it 90 or 270degrees. You can chain textboxes so that your text flows over page breaks. I haven't tried it, but possibly worth it before you chuck all of your computing kit out of the window :-)

I would do that, but it reckon it would only create a new problem, the paper not being 6x4 inch (15,24x 10,16cm), I think I rather need a solution that allows me to choose the right option in the printer menus - ?

Re. 15x10 v. 6x4 etc, sorry, 15cm x 10cm and 6in x 4in are interchangeable in my mind as far as paper sizes are concerned. I assume you have tried the "North America 4x 6" setting which is basically for 10x15 size paper. Or perhaps set Breite to 15cm and Höhe to 10cm in your custom size. (Also, ISTR that with some printers it is only possible to get images to print right up to the paper edge (I.e. "borderless") and not text.
